# Deprecated ReplaceWith doesn't work with generics

Tags: kotlin

I got a function `old(clazz: Class<T>)`, I want to deprecate and guide usage of it to `new<T>()` function.

```kotlin
fun <T> old(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    TODO()
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified T> new(): T {
    return old(T::class.java)
}
```

If I write

```kotlin
@Deprecated(message = "replace with new<T>()", replaceWith = ReplaceWith("new<T>()"))
fun <T> old(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    TODO()
}

// auto correction of
val foo = old(String::class.java)
// becomes
val foo = new()
```

Auto correction of a code `val foo = old(String::class.java)` suggests "replace with 'new()' and ends up looking like this:
`val foo = new()`, which is incorrect, compilation error and miss generics.

But, if I change ReplaceWith pattern to `"new<T remove>()"` for example, which doesn't make sense,  but auto correction correctly identifies generics and replaces it correctly and logically it also concats "remove" to it like this:

```kotlin
// ReplaceWith with "remove" at the end of generics
@Deprecated(message = "replace with new<T>()", replaceWith = ReplaceWith("new<T remove>()"))
fun <T> old(clazz: Class<T>): T {
    TODO()
}

// usage of old
val foo = old(String::class.java)

// becomes (almost correctly)
val foo = new < String remove >()
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? How to define correct pattern for ReplaceWith which leverage inline reified generics in it ?

Comment: seems multiple issues tracked related to issue
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-11679/ReplaceWith-replacing-method-call-to-property-set-ends-up-removing-the-line-of-code

Comment: I saw few of them. I guess, this is another one, so I have created new issue
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-23957/ReplaceWith-incorrectly-removes-generics-information